# reading a string from scanner and converting it to character array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

here is a code i wrote in java, I'm still a beginner in a java so if this is a noob mistake please rectify it and also provide alternative solutions for reading the string and converting it to char array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   String str = s.nextLine();
   char[] c = str.toCharArray(str);
   int x=0,y=0;
   for(int i=0;i<=str.length;i++)
   {
      if(c[i]=='L')
        {
            x=x+1;
        }
    else if(c[i]=='R')
        {
            x=x-1;
        }
        else if(c[i]=='U')
        {
            y=y-1;
        }
        else if(c[i]=='D')
        {
            y=y-1;
        }
   }
    System.out.println(x+""+y);
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> 10: error: method `toCharArray` in class String cannot be applied to
>   given types;
>
> no arguments String actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   12: error: cannot find symbol
>
> variable length variable str of type String

Comment: it's str.length() not str.length

Answer (score 2):

You put an argument in a function that doesn't take any:

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray(str);
```

Just use

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray();
```

For more info, see the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Method str.toCharArray(str); doesn't exist. toCharArray takes no arguments. Replace with str.toCharArray()

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers (I don't take credit for these)

You put an argument in a function that doesn't take any:

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray(str);
```

Just use

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray();
```

-by Arc676

And also note that

it's str.length() not str.length

-by TomN

Both are correct answers

Also, I noticed that you have (I do take credit for these)

```
for(int i=0;i<=str.length;i++)
```

It should be '<', not '<=' to avoid an out of bounds exception

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
```

Also, just a tip:

```
System.out.println(x+""+y);
```

I think you missed putting a space in those quotation marks.